# what is wrong with this plotting code?

Tags: plotting, homework

Heres the question:
 The region bounded by f(x) = x+2 and g(x) = sin(x) between x = 0 and x = Pi/2

i. Plot the region on the interval [0,Pi/2], between y = 0 and y = 4.
ii. Find the area of the region.

Here is what I have done so far: 
Plot[f[x], g[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}]

I have that and it won't even plot my graph. Can someone please help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You need the first argument of Plot to be a list, {f[x],g[x]} followed by domain of interest. I assume you have defined the functions,e.g. as in the answer. If things a awry. Quit kernel and start again. If you have further issue either edit question or ask one focusing on what the problem is :)

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_] := x + 2;
g[x_] := Sin[x];

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, Pi/2},
 PlotRange -> {-0.1, 3.65},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Filling -> (1 -> {2}),
 Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> {Directive[Thick, Magenta],
   Line[{{#, g[#]}, {#, f[#]}}] & /@
    {0, Pi/2}}]
```

[image]

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[g[x] <= y <= f[x] && 0 <= x <= Pi/2, {x, y}];

RegionPlot[rgn, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

The area is

```
Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}]

(*  -1 + Pi + Pi^2/8  *)

% // N

(*  3.37529  *)
```

Or

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[rgn,
  AccuracyGoal -> 7,
  PrecisionGoal -> 7]]

(*  3.37529  *)
```

Or

```
RegionMeasure[DiscretizeRegion[rgn,
  AccuracyGoal -> 7,
  PrecisionGoal -> 7]]

(*  3.37529  *)
```